# Is there a word for "If you really want to know..."

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a word that I can use to start a sentence which would indicate that the rest of the sentence gives information which isn't really important.

For example:

> If you want to know, I saw that same black car yesterday on the parking lot.

The only word I could think of is the word *Informatively* but it doesn't really have the same tone like in the example.

Comment: Incidentally?  .

Comment: *FYI*, *BTW*, *FWIW*,...

Comment: As a matter of general information, I saw that same black car...

Comment: ***Verily***.. .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can think of a few ways to start the sentence,

- Interestingly enough
- Believe it or not
- Incidentally/By the way

**Interestingly enough** can be used to "introduce a piece of information that the speaker finds surprising and interesting" ([Cambridge Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/interestingly)).

> Interestingly enough, I saw that same black car yesterday on the parking lot.

**Believe it or not** means "you may choose to accept something as true or not; it may seem amazing but it's true" ([The Free Dictionary](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/believe+it+or+not)).

> Believe it or not, I saw that same black car yesterday on the parking lot.

[Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/incidentally) defines **incidentally** as "by way of interjection or digression :  by the way".

> Incidentally, I saw that same black car yesterday on the parking lot.
>
> By the way, I saw that same black car yesterday on the parking lot.